# How to use Negative Lookahead in Regex to Delete unwanted Lines

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I need help regarding using negative lookahead. I am using Notepad++ and I want to delete all lines except the lines that contain `<title>(.*)</title>`

I tried a couple of things but that didnt work.

```
^.*(?!<title>).*</title>
^.*(?!<title>.*</title>)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are close:

```
^(?!.*<title>.*</title>).*
```

By this regex `^.*(?!<title>.*</title>)`, the regex engine will just find some position that it cannot find `<title>.*</title>` (end of line is one such valid position).

You need to make sure that, from the start of the line, there is no way you can find `<title>.*</title>` anywhere in the line. That is what my regex does.

Comment: add \r\n(windows) or \n(linux) at the end to remove/delete that lines